# Xcode 6.3 missing unit test status/run in editor

Tags: unit-testing, testing, xctest, xcode6.3

I just upgraded to Xcode 6.3 and I have lost the unit test status/run indicators that were displayed in the left gutter of the editor. The status/run indicators don't immediately show in the Test Navigator either until after I perform a compile and test (Ctrl-U). After the tests have run the Test Navigator will display the status/run indicators but the status/run indicators in the editor are never displayed.

Has anyone else noticed this? I would really need to get these back. I hope someone knows how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry. I thought I'd read through the Apple's latest release notes for Xcode, but I apparently missed this part. Thanks anyway.

> Swift tests are not automatically discovered in this release of Xcode.
>   Test annotations in the source editor sidebar will not appear, and the
>   test navigator and the table of tests in the Test action of the scheme
>   sheet will be empty. You can run Swift tests by selecting Product >
>   Test. Once tests have been run, they appear in the test navigator and
>   the scheme sheet. The following limitations apply:
>
> Tests discovered through execution in this manner provide limited
>   interaction in the test navigator. For example, Run buttons do not
>   appear and clicking on a test in the navigator does not jump to the
>   source code except in the case of a test error. Run buttons and test
>   success/fail indicators will not appear in the source editor.
>   (20373533)

Comment: One step forward, two steps back.

Comment: After running the whole test suit at least once you can then right click on individual tests and select "Text XXX" to run that single test again... But each time you add a new test you have to run them all again to discover them... sigh.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that too. Also if you rename an existing test it keeps the old test name and adds the new one when you run all.

Comment: So this makes it impossible to set a baseline for performance tests?

Comment: So all my tests are gone in the scheme, I can't run them, the scheme does not see them. How can I run them and or making them appear in the scheme like they used to?

Comment: Right now the only way I know to do it is to run the whole suite of tests either by clicking the little arrow to the right of the test file in the Test Navigator or by clicking Cmd-U. Hopefully they'll get this fixed soon.

Comment: I just updated to the latest Xcode. It's recognizing tests again!

Comment: how do you just set the baselines then for performance testing ?

Answer (score 0):

This bug in XCode 6.3 is fixed in XCode 6.3.1.

Gerd